# Jquery Text Swap - Multiple Use Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

So I used a script that I found on Stack Overlow to swap text. It worked great initially but then I tried to use it again on the same page and I noticed an issue.

You can see the problem here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AX4LC/2/)

**The HTML**

```
<div class="gallerycard">
    <div id="textMessage"></div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="girlname">ONE LEFT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="newgirl">TWO LEFT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="girlimage"></div>
    <div class="girlinfo">TEXT</div>
</div>
<div class="gallerycard">
    <div id="textMessage"></div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="girlname">ONE RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="newgirl">TWO RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="girlimage"></div>
    <div class="girlinfo">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

**The Jquery**

```
var cnt=0, texts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});
function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('fast').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 800).fadeOut('fast', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
slide()
```

So, how do I keep them from merging?

Answer (score 0):

You need two arrays, one for each,
give each one of the gallerycards different ids
and do it twice

```
var cnt=0, firstTexts=[], secondTexts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$('#firstID > .textContent').each(function() {
  firstTexts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});

cnt = 0;
// save the texts in an array for re-use
$('#secondID > .textContent').each(function() {
  secondTexts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});
```

and call slide twice with the relevant array and id

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems based entirely on too much copy/paste without understanding the why.

Both target divs have the same id. You should never have two elements on the same page which share the same id. Now there is a quick and dirty way to clean this up and there is a flexible and effective way to clean this up. I went for the flexible solution and I'll explain how it works as best I can.

```
<div class="gallerycard" data-target="textMessageLeft">
    <div id="textMessageLeft"></div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="girlname">ONE LEFT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="newgirl">TWO LEFT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="girlimage"></div>
    <div class="girlinfo">TEXT</div>
</div>
<div class="gallerycard" data-target="textMessageRight">
    <div id="textMessageRight"></div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="girlname">ONE RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="textContent">
        <div class="newgirl">TWO RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="girlimage"></div>
    <div class="girlinfo">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Notice I added a data-target element to the gallerycard containing the id of the div we want to place the text into. I also changed the ids on each target div to be unique. This is critical to make it all work, as is the data-target element matching those ids.

```
texts = {};

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function () {
    var target = $(this).parent().attr('data-target');
    if (texts[target] == null) { texts[target] = []; }
    texts[target].push($(this).text());
});

function slide(divId, cnt) {
    if (cnt >= texts[divId].length) cnt = 0;
    $('#' + divId).html(texts[divId][cnt++]);
    $('#' + divId)
        .fadeIn('fast').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 800).fadeOut('fast',

    function () {
        return slide(divId,cnt)
    });
}

for (var t in texts)
{
    slide(t, 0);
}
```

In the javascript I changed a lot to make this an expandable and flexible solution, rather than simply duplicating what was already there with two separate names.

First, we removed the counter and changed texts to an object (`{}` instead of `[]`). From here I can use texts like a hash, which simplifies the rest of the script. The key of the hash is the value of the data-target from the container div of the message and content divs. Add as many content divs as you want under each parent and they'll all be found and associated correctly.

The texts from each textContent div are stored in an array, but we are using the push() function to eliminate the need for a counter variable - counters are fine for a single instance, but they get ugly with multiples.

I changed the slide function to accept two variables: `divId` and `cnt`. divId is how the slider knows which div to target and cnt allows the recursive call to keep a private counter which will not conflict with other instances of the slider function running simultaneously.

Finally, to again prevent duplication and allow further expansion, Instead of simply calling slide, we iterate through the hash to get the divId and call a slide instance for each divId we have. Go ahead and try expanding the number of panes or adding new textContent divs under one of the headers. It all works very smoothly now.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/AX4LC/4/